# Mini-batches in RL

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I just read the paper of [Mnih (2013)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf) and was really wondering about the aspect that he talks about using RMSprop with **minibatches of size 32** (page 6).

My understanding of these kinds of reinforcement learning algorithms is, that there is only 1 or at least very little amount of training samples per fit, and in every fit I update the network.
Whereas in supervised learning I have up to millions of samples and divide them in minibatches of e.g. 32 and update the network after every minibatch, which makes sense.

So my question is: If I put only one sample into the neural network at a time, how does minibatches make sense? Did I understand something wrong about that concept?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper you mentioned introduces two mechanisms that stabilize Q-Learning method when used with a deep neural network function approximator. One of the mechanisms is called Experience Replay, and it is basically a memory buffer for observed experiences. You can find the description in the paper in the end of the fourth page. Instead of learning from the single experience you have just seen, you save it to the buffer. Learning is done every N iterations and you sample a random minibatch of experiences from the replay buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Filip is correct.  Just to add intuition to his answer, the reason why an experience replay is used is to decorrelate the experiences that the RL experienced.  This is essential when non-linear function approximation is used such as neural networks.

Example:  Imagine if you had 10 days to study for a chemistry and math test, and both test were on the same day.  If you spend the first 5 days on chemistry and last 5 days on math, you would have forgotten most of the chemistry you studied.  A neural network behaves similarly.

[image]

By decorrelating the experiences, a more general policy can be identified through the training data.

And while training the neural network, we have a batch of memory (i.e., data), and we sample random mini-batches of 32 from them to do supervised learning, just as any other neural network is trained.